# Роли и права для Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, доступ

Есть ли какая статья относящиеся к установке на Laravel 7 прав и ролей для пользователей ?
То что находил - они все на версию 4 или 5, плагины просто не ставятся. 
Или же может есть какой то другой способ для установки прав и ролей ?
Проект не маленький, хотелось бы управлять пользователями и их ролями.
Приблизительно будет их 8 штук, и у всех разные права , но какие то права будут одинаковые.
Для Yii2 нашел способ как сделать, там ставиться плагин RBAC и очень удобное управление при помощи админ панели, а на Laravel я такого не нашел, или просто не увидел того что надо .

Comment: `spatie/laravel-permission`

Comment: [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Comment: Используйте политики или guards https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: @InDevX, Я вообще не могу сообразить как с ним разобраться , даже после просмотра и чтения документации.